# Rank and Pseudo Inverse of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear transformation   $L(x) = Ax$ from $ℝ^m → ℝ^n$.

The pseudo inverse $L^+$ of $L$ is the transformation from $ℝ^n → ℝ^m$ given by minimal least-squares solution of the system $L(x) = y$

Question: 
Suppose $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n$

Find the matrix for $L^+$.

proof: $\operatorname{rank}(A) = n$  implies that $\operatorname{image}(A)$ spans $ℝ^n$. From this, $\ker(A^T) = \operatorname{im}(A)^\perp = \{0\}$.

this is where I get stuck. Don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Anyone there...?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The least squares solution solves the equation
$$
A^TA x = A^Ty
$$
In this case, we can note that $A^TA$ is a square matrix with full rank.

Comment: Yes. I understand this, but how do I proceed with my proof?

Comment: That equation should be $A^TAx = \color{red}{A^T}y$.

Comment: @Artem solve for $x$